# WXPYTHON CUSTOM DIALOG

Tags: wxpython, customdialog

I have create some custom dialogs in wxpython that I am very happy with.  I can execute pretty much anything I want based on user interaction and then once "OK" is selected collect the information from whatever functions I have run.

What I am wondering is there a way to execute a final function at the time "OK" is selected.  I do not have any sample code because I am not sure where to start and the demo does not do this, if it did my question would be answered by that.

So lets say that in the dialog I have calculated A and B and when "OK" is selected I want to execute C = str(A) + "whatever" + str(B)

So that upon exit I can dlg.C.GetValue() =

Comment: WHY ALL CAPS IN TITLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create `self.C` in your custom dialog's `__init__` method. Then bind your OK button to a handler and update it as you mentioned. Then you should be able to get its value just as you stated: `value = dlg.C.GetValue()`.

One thing to keep in mind is that when you create the OK button, do **not** set its id to `wx.OK`. If you do, it may not call your custom event handler as `wx.OK` is a special id that has a special default handler.